pantsbuild remote execution refusing to run on remote machine
I am tring to use the remote execution feature built in pants
running the example-repi-server they provide with minor changes in the docker file to for it to fit my project, I am able to run my project using remote execution on a local docker but when I run the same docker on a different machine in the same network and (after updating the pants.toml the match the new IP of-course) I get this error:
native_engine.IntrinsicError: Unavailable: "error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)"

I can ping the machine and I have a open ssh session to it so it's not some basic network error
but I have no idea why pants refuses to connect to it
My remote machine is using a different architecture but I am running python and i have all the appropriate interpreters installed and configured

It might not be the prettiest solution but I changed the docker's network type to "host"
for exemple by adding --network=host to the docker run command line
More specific for this case
if you are using the example provided by pants like me in the file run.sh
replace the -p flag (line 14 i believe) with the --network=host flag
